# Nagell-Lutz Theorem applied to non-Weierstrass form curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Could someone please explain how to apply the Nagell-Lutz theorem to non-Weierstrass normal form elliptic curves in order to find all the torsion points / points of finite order.
If the answer to this is to simply convert to Weierstrass form, could this transformation please be explained in simple terms?

Thanks

Jamal

Comment: The answer is to convert (birationally) to the Weierstrass normal form, since the result https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagell%E2%80%93Lutz_theorem (and its generalization in *loc. cit.*) wants this form. The transformation is rather standard, but we need an elliptic curve equation and a (rational) point on the curve. Is the most general cubic the start? Take a look at Ian Connell's excelent exposition https://webs.ucm.es/BUCM/mat/doc8354.pdf, Cubic to Weierstrass.